# Using Qt in Java?

Tags: java, qt

Is it possible to use Qt in Java SE?

Comment: Hey youngsters, back in the day they allowed questions like this at SO.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The current best option appears to be the [Bytedeco bindings](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/qt), which are JNI bindings to native C++ Qt libraries. They are not officially supported by the Qt Project, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: the project seems dead.

Comment: Any alternative libraries? This one is quite dead.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: link to qtjambi is invalid

Comment: I am seeing https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/qt, which is alive as of now (2021).

Answer (score 5):

Here are some useful tutorial for you:

- [Java desktop development with Qt Jambi](http://web.archive.org/web/20170531121041/http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077750/core-java/java-desktop-development-with-qt-jambi.html)
- [Working with Qt Applications - NetBeans IDE 6.9 Tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20120422034217/http://netbeans2.org/kb/docs/cnd/qt-applications.html)

Answer (score 4):

I believe it can be done using JNI (Java Native Interface) calls. There is also [Jambi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi)

Answer (score 3):

[QT Jambi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi) and a good article about it in javaworld [Java desktop development with Qt Jambi](http://web.archive.org/web/20170531121041/http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077750/core-java/java-desktop-development-with-qt-jambi.html)

and here is [QT Jambi documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20140809054302/http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-index.html)