# Can I develop Java GUI using Qt?

Tags: java, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Qt in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577313/using-qt-in-java)

I have the question if I can write GUI applications in Java using Qt rather than Swing? Which IDE should I use? Any tutorial?

Comment: Just wondering, if there's a QT driver for SWT ?